# Get correct return type value in our factory loader pattern

Tags: typescript

The following example is working (in JavaScript), but I can't get the correct return types in TypeScript working. Depending on the factory object, is should know the correct return type of the "func" function.

We want to use this pattern for dynamically add and get DataLoaders.

```
class Dog {
  bark() { console.log("wuff")}
}
class Cat {
  miau() { console.log("miau")}
}

class FactoryItem<T extends () => {}> {
  constructor(public func: T) {}
}

class Factories {
  factories = new Map();
  
  add<T extends () => {}> (factories: FactoryItem<T>) {
    this.factories.set(factories,factories.func())
  }

  get<T extends FactoryItem<()=>{}>>(factory:T):ReturnType<typeof factory.func> {  // this is not working
    return this.factories.get(factory)
  }
}

const factoryA = new FactoryItem(() => new Dog());
const factoryB = new FactoryItem(() => new Cat());

const factories = new Factories();
factories.add(factoryA)
factories.add(factoryB)

factories.get(factoryA).bark(); // typescript is not happy
//factorys.get(factoryB).bark(); // this must fail
factories.get(factoryB).miau(); // typescript is not happy
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ali-habibzadeh/837084089426b9670ee562fa3c3646d5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function's return type-

```
  get<T extends FactoryItem<()=>{}>>(factory: T):ReturnType<typeof factory.func> {  // this is not working
    return this.factories.get(factory)
  }
```

You're claiming that the return type of `get` is the return type of `factory.func` - but this is just a **constant type** that is *not dependent* on the **generic type**.

If you want your return type to be influenced by the generic type - you must *use* the generic type, aka `T`-

```
  get<T extends FactoryItem<()=>{}>>(factory: T):ReturnType<T['func']> {
    return this.factories.get(factory)
  }
```

Remember, the context of the generic during usage of the generic function is *only* captured by the generic type (in this case `T`) - so any time you want to construct a type *based* on the captured context, you need to do that in terms of the generic type parameter (in this case `T`).

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAsAKGtARmATgNYAUAlKtMPAHYTwgCmAdCEsQEQDuArgGa-tSAX0wiMoSDADCYAC6pM2ALYBLMNzIUqtes1aIOq9YLFjMEqNABiYYLPj4AngElZDJQB4AKtAYAPN2oAExhNAF4APjgkaAAfaBlZKPQsShoIWXxuOwdiAAduHBAVYGhebmpgAC5oL3IUU0xzcEsbHPwVBhgU7F5bew6u6DDoagZOaABZMDyyAG5FaEWwIKDvXwCGYNDySOjkeMSo4j72zogatoGXN08vCPrF7FkACxUIJlOB86YIBlkTv0HOcADRfYFdT4VYBkUiLMypRD-db+QIhaxApyudwecJRBAHBJyCIRQHtRw1Oo1ABK-24+GoXkceQY3gA2gBycqVDkAXWS2AA9ILoK93tBxdR4PJOA5CCpqIgntB8HSGaK3h9wYMPkiAdrHHDUo0MOZ0vIDQBBYajcYY8nYpTEPG2iYE2ELcTmsqYxwAIRtYwmVwcN3czt2USDRIBpFInrNtAtmPOgbtIZ180w2p+KyCZOulqNOcheYLob9RuzKchevLTiLTDwRHm0GFouZXWAHTy8kl0ugLxmeUc1fJuv+9f9pCbBBI8bbIrFMCU3AyPpUIDH31rk4NlaYRg0C-bsk7EG7Kl7EpgUvkQ7yI8wQA)

Comment: This works and is somewhat helpfull but it requires the Factories class to now Dog and Cat. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @brenkdar That's an unnecessary change I put on the playground. It's just good practice, has nothing to do with the solution. You can ignore that if you like

Comment: Great! I didn't understood that.